# Radio button that filter through products javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, filtering, product

I have my data.json long list of products that I fetched in js. I need to create radio buttons that filters through the products shown and I am not sure how!
I have picked the data i need to filter through and save them i separate arrays, like this: (it's cars and vehicles)

```
getData().then(data => {
            // Brands array      
            const brands = Object.values(data).map(({brand}) => brand);
            console.log(brands);
            // Model year
            const modelYears = Object.values(data).map(({model_year}) => model_year);
            console.log(modelYears);
            // Other datas...
```

The problem is that I have multiple cars with the same year or the same brand, I need to write a function that look at the checked button radio and show all the cars with that brand / that year of production...

```
 <form id="brands">
            <p>MERKER:</p>
            <input type="radio" id="challenger" name="brand" value="challenger">
            <label for="challenger">Challenger</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="euromobil" name="brand" value="euromobil">
            <label for="euromobil">Eura Mobil</label><br>
            <input type="radio" id="dethleffs" name="brand" value="dethleffs">
            <label for="dethleffs">Dethleffs</label><br>
```

Any input or idea would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can use [array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form id="brands">
        <p>MERKER:</p>
        <input type="radio" id="honda" name="brand" value="honda">
        <label for="honda">Honda</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="toyota" name="brand" value="toyota">
        <label for="toyota">Toyota</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="fiat" name="brand" value="fiat">
        <label for="fiat">Fiat</label><br>
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
<script>


  
var readTextFile = function(file, callback) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
         rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
                 resolve (callback(rawFile.responseText));
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    });
}
    var brands = document.forms["brands"].elements["brand"];    
    var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');
    // Add event listener to each radio button
    function bind (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        for (let brand of brands){
            brand.addEventListener("click", function (){
                var resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
                resultsDiv.innerText ='';
                for (let item in data)
                {
                  // console.log( data[item].brand);
                    
                    if (brand.getAttribute('id') === data[item].brand)
                    {
                        console.log(data[item].model_year);
                        resultsDiv.innerText += `brand : ${data[item].brand} 
                                                   model_year: ${data[item].model_year}  
                                                   price: ${data[item].price}\n`;
                    }
                }
                
            });
         
        }
        
    };
    
     readTextFile("./cars.json", function(text){
        var data =   JSON.parse(text);
      
        return data;
        // return self.data;
         
    }).then(result => bind(result));

    
    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Related json sample in cars.json:

```
{
    "car1"  : {"brand" : "fiat", "model_year": 2010, "price" : 33000   },
    "car2"  : {"brand" : "honda", "model_year": 2015, "price" : 120000   },
    "car3"  : {"brand" : "toyota", "model_year": 2012, "price" : 200000   },
    "car4"  : {"brand" : "fiat", "model_year": 2010, "price" : 33000   },
    "car5"  : {"brand" : "honda", "model_year": 2015, "price" : 120000   }

}
```